# How to create templates folder inside of an app in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates

So Basically I like to create templates folder in main project directory and than I just create HTML file inside of it.

But now I want to create this templates folder inside of an app.

How can I do it?

Thanks Good people in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually create a ***templates*** folder in any of your app. For as long as you have put in the this code inside your ***settings.py***

**settings.py**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        ...
    },
]
```

You can refer to the official docs of django here [Overriding templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/overriding-templates/)